# Autocovariance matrix for VAR(1) case

Tags: self-study, vector-autoregression

According to Lutkepohl (2005) autocovariance matrix for VAR(1) case is given by 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma_y(h) &= E(y_t - \mu)(y_{t-h} - \mu)' \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}A_1^iE(u_{t-i}u'_{t-h-j})(A_1^j)' \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}A_1^{h+i}\Sigma_u(A_1^i)' \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}A_1^{h+i}\Sigma_u(A_1^i)' 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
since $E(u_tu_s') = 0$ for $s\neq t$ and $E(u_tu_t') = \Sigma_u \;\; \forall t$.

I have troubles with getting from second to third line. I understand that since $E(u_tu_s') = 0$ for $s\neq t$, the term $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}A_1^iE(u_{t-i}u'_{t-h-j})(A_1^j)'$ is zero unless $i = h+j$ (and hence $j = i-h$). So I remove summation over $j$ and set $j = i - h$. I get expression
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}A_1^i\Sigma_u(A_1^{i-h})'.$$

How do I get to the expression in the book?

Comment: The autocovariance function is an even function of $h$. Try removing summation over $i$, setting $i=h+j$,  to get $$\Gamma_y(h) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A_1^{h+j}\Sigma_u(A_1^j)'.$$ Then, replace $j$ by $i$

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, thanks for your comment, that worked.